# Проблема с IF в ruby

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Enter first day"
a = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Enter second day"
b = gets.chomp.to_i

if (a == "monday")
  n1 = 1
end

...

if (a == "sunday")
  n1 = 7
end

if (b == "monday")
  n2 = 1
end
...

end

if (b == "sunday")
  n2 = 7
end
```

line 51:

```
dif = n2 - n1

if (dif < -1)
  puts "YES"
else 
  puts "NO"
end
```

В командной строке выходит:

```
in line 51 
in '<main>': undefined method '-' for nill:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Говорит что `n1` и `n2` не существуют.

Как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = gets.chomp.to_i
#             ^^^^^
```

Вы преобразуете введённую **строку** в **число**...

```
if (a == "monday")
```

...а потом сравниваете **число** со **строкой**.

В Ruby **сильная типизация**. Это разные типы данных, а оператор равенства строк и чисел на различных типах всегда возвращает `false`. Ваше условие просто никогда не выполнится.

Проследите, какой тип имеет каждое значение в вашей программе и убедитесь, что там то, что вы ожидаете.

---

Вас может заинтересовать, почему не было `NameError`, если в итоге в переменную так ничего и не попало. Откуда там взялся `nil`. Есть очень показательный случай, демонстрирующий, откуда такое поведение:

```
x = x # ...когда `x` не определён
# => nil
```

Синтаксис Ruby устроен таким образом, что локальные переменные в коде можно увидеть заранее. Интерпретатор инициализирует **все** *локальные* переменные участка кода в `nil` **до** начала его выполнения.

Конкретно в этой строчке интерпретатор видит, что `x` локальная переменная и в неё происходит присваивание. Поэтому когда исполнение начинается, там уже лежит `nil`.

Comment: исчерпывающий отвеет (-: